# Given that $2^ny+1 \mid x^{2^n}-1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $x=1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Given that $2^ny+1 \mid x^{2^n}-1$,  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $x=1$

I can't find a way to start... Any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is an I.M.O 2012 shortlist question. You can find the solution here. https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2012SL.pdf **Question N6.**